# Ajax Communication: Malformed JSON string in Perl

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, perl

I want to send by XMLHttpRequest a JSON object to a Perl Script (*.cgi)
But I can't decode the JSON object in the cgi file.

I always reveive the error message:

> > malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before
> >      "(end of string)")

This is my javascript code:

```jscript
//ajax communication for receiver/transceiver 
function doAjaxRequest(query) 
{
    if(whatReq == "")
    {
        alert('ERROR: Request-Type undefined');
        return;
    }   

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        arequest = new top.XMLHttpRequest(); // Mozilla, Safari, Opera
    }   
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        try 
        {
            arequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); // IE 5
        } 
        catch (e) 
        {
            try 
            {
                arequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); // IE 6
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert('ERROR: Request not possible');
                return;
            }
        }   
    }

    if (!arequest) 
    {
        alert("Kann keine XMLHTTP-Instanz erzeugen");
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        var url = "****.cgi";

        var dp = document.location.pathname;

        arequest.open('post', url, true);
        arequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        //receiver function
        arequest.onreadystatechange =   function() 
                                        {       
                                            switch (arequest.readyState) 
                                            {
                                                case 4:

                                                    if (arequest.status != 200) 
                                                    {
                                                        alert("Der Request wurde abgeschlossen, ist aber nicht OK\nFehler:"+arequest.status);
                                                    } 
                                                    else 
                                                    {
                                                        var content = arequest.responseText;
                                                        analyseResponse(content);
                                                    }           
                                                break;

                                                default:
                                                        //alert("DEFAULT:" + arequest.readyState );
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
        //transceiver function
        query="jsonObj=" + JSON.stringify({name:"John Rambo", time:"2pm"});
        alert(query);
        arequest.send(query)
    }
}
```

And here the cgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $jsonObj =  param('jsonObj');
my $json  = JSON->new->utf8;
my $input = $json->decode( $jsonObj  );

print Dumper(\$input);
```

Can you help me? I don't know how to access the JSON object.

Thank you very much.

Comment: We need to see the JSON string. Try printing it. But at a guess - because you're pulling it as a parameter, it's URI encoded. You'll have to decode that first.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to `arequest.send("jsonObj="+query)` ?

Comment: I do an alert before starting the query: JSON 
 
name
 "John Rambo"
 
time
 "2pm"

Comment: You are getting the error that you are, because the thing getting to `decode` doesn't start with the 'normal' characters you might expect from JSON text. `print Dumper $jsonObj;` might enlighten.

Comment: @glennjackman yes, you are right, I lost it during the past edits. The problem is still the same.

Comment: my $test =  param('jsonObj');
print Dumper(\$test);
results->malformed header from script. Bad header=$VAR1 = \undef;: accmanagertest.cgi

Comment: You have not output an HTTP header from your script. Since you have CGI::Carp, just `die Dumper $test` and the `fatalsToBrowser` will take care of it for you. Unless of course you are expecting a JSON reply explicitly, in which case you would have to go check your servers error logs. Of course you can also inspect the message using the development tools in your browser. I.e. in Chrome, press F12, go to Network, send the AJAX request, click the thing that shows up in the list and read.

Answer (score 1):

This message says you've got non-JSON string in `$jsonObj`. One particulary common case is empty string. Try printing out raw content of `$jsonObj` and make sure you set up everything correctly for `CGI::param` to work and also check with browser's built in tools that it actually sends data.

Also I highly suggest you throwing away 10 years old ActiveX shit. You're using `JSON.stringify` and all the browsers that support it also support native `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to vote to put your question on hold because of [insufficient information to reproduce and diagnose the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but then I realized that your question *does* contain enough clues to figure out what's wrong — they're just really well hidden.

- **Clue #1**: Your error message says (**emphasis** mine):

  > malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, **at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")**

This implies that your `$jsonObj` variable has length 0, i.e. it is empty.

So, what's causing it to be empty?  Well, the Perl code looks like perfectly standard CGI stuff, so the problem must be either in your JS code, or in something that your haven't showed us (such as your web server config).  Since we can't debug what we can't see, let's focus on your JS code, where we find...

- **Clue #2**: There's something wrong with this line:

  ```
  arequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  ```

Of course, you *can* set [any content type you want](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers/31231#31231) for a POST request, but CGI.pm expects to receive the content in one of the standard formats for HTML form submissions, i.e. [either *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* or *multipart/form-data*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4).  When it receives something labeled as *application/json* instead, it doesn't know how to parse it, and so won't.  Thus, the `param()` method in your Perl script will return nothing, since, as far as it's concerned, the client sent no parameters that it could understand.

There *should* have been a warning about this somewhere in your web server error logs, but you presumably didn't think to check those.  (Hint: you really should!)

(You could've also used [the `warningsToBrowser` option of CGI::Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html#MAKING-WARNINGS-APPEAR-AS-HTML-COMMENTS) to get those warnings sent as HTML comments, but I guess you weren't aware of that option, either.  Also, to make that work reliably, you'd really need to `use` CGI::Carp *before* the CGI module, so that it can catch any early errors.)

Anyway, the fix is simple: just replace `application/json` in your JS code with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, since that's what what you're actually trying to send to the server.  You should also make sure that your JSON data actually *is* properly URL-encoded before embedding it in the request, by passing the output of `JSON.stringify()` through `encodeURIComponent()`, like this:

```
var data = {name:"John Rambo", time:"2pm"};
var query = "jsonObj=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
```

(I'll also second Oleg V. Volkov's suggestion to get rid of all the obsolete ActiveX stuff in your JS code.  In fact, you could do even better by using a modern JS utility library like, say, jQuery, which provides convenient wrapper functions so that you don't even have to mess with XMLHttpRequest directly.)